# Suggestion for a sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning, hypercorrection

It leads to inhibition of protein synthesis is take place.

Is it a wrong statement ?

If it is a wrong statement , could you please make a sentence for me which have same meaning as stated by above sentence .

Comment: The sentence is not grammatically correct. Can you try to explain what is the intended meaning? Otherwise we have to guess what you want it to mean.

Comment: @auspicious99 what's is wrong with above sentence , please let me know .does not it carry any meaning ? please suggest me a paid English grammar lesson which is very much needed for me .I am struggling with English grammar.

Comment: 'It leads to the inhibition of protein synthesis'..........'taking place' is implicit and redundant.

Comment: I agree with Bruce Murray on this. @Rid I'm not aware of a good source of paid English grammar lessons, but there's another stack exchange site for learning English that you may want to take a look at, https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Bruce Murray yeah it is used as repeated meaning .is it a grammatically correct sentence or not ?

Comment: @Rid, your sentence is not grammatically correct.  I echo the previous comment in that you will find a much warmer reception to your questions in the ELL forum.  I think here is more for people who want an in-depth insight rather than basic grammar correction.  Here is the link: https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: 'It leads to inhibition of protein synthesis is take place' is not grammatically correct.  'It leads to inhibition of protein synthesis taking place' is grammatically correct, but, as mentioned, 'taking place' is a redundant term that you may choose to omit for the sake of concise prose.

Comment: @Rid Or *it leads to the inhibition of protein synthesis **from taking** place.* (And I do **not** agree with previous comments that *taking place* is necessarily redundant. It depends on the context.) But all of the variations of the sentence depend on exactly what you're trying to say. Since the original sentence is not only ungrammatical but also ambiguous, it's not possible to suggest a rephrasing without knowing what its intention is.

Comment: @Jason Bassford Thanks for your valuable suggestions.'From taking place ' is making sense to me 